# How do I consistently keep my RAM usage low?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have a decent 8 GB of RAM, yet I'm frequently running into memory trouble.

I just now went about closing the dozen apps open , and it looks like so :

[image]

How do I keep it this way, though?  And what is a "safe" memory situation - should I aim for 50% free RAM, or 25% free RAM?

I'm always running into issues with this. It bugs me to have a slow clogged computer.

I dabbled with some techniques, like minimizing the number of open Firefox tabs.  But then I'd cave in, disabling the restriction.

I'm just looking for tips, on how to reduce my RAM usage. I have **8 GB**  , not 512 MB !! thanks!

Comment: Isn't the goal of RAM to load anything you can in it ? It's way faster than any mechanical hard drive and faster than most SSDs. You should only worry when reaching ~90% (depending on your amount of RAM), before starting a RAM consuming application or when you are using your HDD to cache data.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus  - Well, not sure... I feel like it gets very unresponsive after around  60%  . but yea I see your point. will try to manage better

Comment: I downloaded some tool called RAMMap , will lok more at   RAM consuming applications

Comment: @Adel You don't have to worry about RAM use... Windows caches stuff a lot.

Comment: @Adel Also, the point of RAM is to use it. Using 4GB today won't let you use 12GB tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe it'll cache less stuff in your ram if you kill your swap file? Not sure this will yield you the response you want. PS - 8GB isn't remarkable. And if you want really fast, there's always Windows 95 ;)

Comment: So apparently I have no idea what I'm talking about , great

Comment: @Adel Probably those apps cause a lot of disk reads/writes and that's why your computer slows down. RAM usage doesn't directly impact performance.

Comment: @Doc -  What's the deal with the swap file ?  I feel like you say it partly in jest ?

Comment: @Adel The swap-file comment isn't in jest. The swap file is a file on your hard drive that your system uses as ram when your memory's full. Hard drives are VASTLY slower than ram so when your system starts depending on your swap, performance suffers. Though, it can be a pleasant alternative to an "out of memory" error. Anyway, your OSes swapping algorithm may not be well suited to your application and you have barely enough memory that turning off swap shouldn't be a major problem. The said, you sensed some jest - that's because I think you're chasing an uncatchable dragon.

Comment: @Doc -  Ok I understand now, thanks very much!   Will study up more on swap files .  And I think you're right re: "uncatchable dragon" . thanks !

Comment: To sum it up (rule of thumb): having lots of RAM used _can_ be a sign of speed, the other way around is not necessarily right ;)

Comment: which issue do you have? RAM is there to be used to SPEED up your PC.

Comment: ??? what do you want to tell me with this reply?

Comment: @magicandre1981 -  No worries ... , it's already been discussed alot Andre... it basically boils down to wat Doc says above me. Otherwise , I need more hardware :-D    .  Probably, more of a "habit " issue  atm (I tend to open too many browser tabs. for e.g. )

Comment: @Doc Turning off swap causes inefficient RAM usage. It's not a good idea, particularly in a low RAM situation. (Without swap, modified unbacked pages *must* be kept in RAM because there's no place else to put them, even if they haven't been accessed in hours.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yeah, and if the system needs access to those pages, they're in ram. I'm not saying it's a good idea, like I said in an earlier comment, he's chasing an uncatchable dragon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just now went about closing the dozen apps open

There's your problem then. Too many RAM-hungry apps open at the same time. Don't worry, not judging, I do the same thing.

Only two possible solutions:

- Don't have so many apps open at the same time
- Install more RAM

Incidentally try **Resource Monitor** to check your RAM usage. You might find a lot of RAM is being used by the OS for *caching*. The OS will give up this RAM to apps when needed, it's all managed automatically. Look at my RAM usage and notice the "Standby" amount.  That's RAM that's used for caching but is available to apps if required:

[image: Resource Monitor RAM Usage]

Comment: And for goodness sakes forget about Swap File tweaking. The OS is exceptionally good at managing RAM and swap file use to enhance performance. Disabling Swap File is done for esoteric reasons and won't offer any useful benefit to 99% users.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding the problem. Having almost all your RAM used is normal. Free RAM doesn't make your system any faster, it just sits their doing nothing.

You may have some actual issue and it might even have something to do with RAM. But nobody will be able to tell from the information you've given. You haven't described the symptoms, the circumstances under which they occur, and so on.

It is perfectly normal for a modern operating system to use pretty much all of the RAM available. Low RAM usage is a symptom of a problem, indicating that your system is wasting RAM rather than using it, and not a good thing.